# Minimum Widget Width for Plugin Development

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, sidebar

I was considering a plugin that inserts itself as a widget in one's sidebar. Trouble is, I don't know what to expect for the minimum width in one's sidebar. Is there a standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i am aware there is "no" standard each sidebar is defined by the theme itself i would create the elements so that they stretch and wrap in your div and use %'s in your css for associated sizes.